# In TFS When I CHeck In a Backlog Item how do i make it change its state to done

Tags: visual-studio

I don't want to use only Tasks in TFS Some times a Bug or a backlog Item are so small that there is no need to create tasks underneath it.  HOw do i automatically make it Mark the Item as done in tfs when i check it in.

[image]

There is no way for me to make it relative in this case.  Because it is a backlog Item as opposed to a Task.

Does anyone have a way to make this work?

Comment: Not 100 percent sure, but I guess you need to add Action into your transitions. Here an example from Task WITD:`<TRANSITION from="Active" to="Closed">
          <ACTIONS>
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
          </ACTIONS>`  If you want to change from any state to Done, you need to create transitions for every state and add the Action.

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio to checkin then it asks for a comment and a work item to associate with the checkin. There is a area where you can provide the state of workitem as Resolve or Associate after this checkin happens you can put the state to resolve it would mark the item as done.